# How to update session storage data without refreshing page?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I am creating a SPA web application and use SessionStorage to store current user information in my browser. I use Chrome for test.
in test progress I found that when user login successfully SessionStorage will updated in console but when I cannot access this added value until i refresh the page.

how can I resolve this problem?

this is my angular service that is responsible for storing and retrieving currentUser in sessionStorage :

```
app.service("sessionStorageService", ["$window","$q", function ($window, $q) {
var deferred = $q.defer();
this.setCurrentUser = function (user) {
    $window.sessionStorage["currentUser"] = JSON.stringify(user);
},
    this.getCurrentUser = function () {
        if ($window.sessionStorage["currentUser"]) {
            console.log("bega") ;
            deferred.resolve(JSON.parse($window.sessionStorage["currentUser"]));
            return deferred.promise;
        } else {
            console.log("bega1") ;
            deferred.reject("No Login User");
            return deferred.promise ;
        }
    };
```

}]);

this store successfully an same time but for retrieving current user I must refresh the page. and because of spa it is impossible for me :(

Comment: can you post your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your issue is linked to the fact you use 1 promise ($q.deffer) instead of creating one at each call

Here your service updated (I use $q.when to return the value without creating a new promise)

```
app.service('sessionStorageService', ['$window', '$q', function ($window, $q) {
    this.setCurrentUser = function (user) {
        $window.sessionStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
    },
    this.getCurrentUser = function () {
        if ($window.sessionStorage.getItem('currentUser')) {
            return $q.when(JSON.parse($window.sessionStorage.getItem('currentUser')));
        } else {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            deferred.reject('No Login User');
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    };
    this.clearCurrentUser = function () {
        $window.sessionStorage.removeItem('currentUser');
    };
}]);
```

I prefer use setItem and getItem method on sessionStorage ...

A working jsfiddle exemple : https://jsfiddle.net/royto/pk8f05La/

Comment: you make my day happy :)